# Bootstrapping for testing set

Tags: random-forest, bootstrap

I know that for fitting a random forest model in a training set, you  create many bootstrap samples with the training data set and fit a decision tree to each bootstrapped training set. Then aggregate predictions from every tree to get the single prediction.

But, the question is, for testing, can you please inform me how it works in an unseen set? I don't think you can create many bootstrap samples with the training data. Do you create bootstrap samples with the test data?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You apply your final aggregated random forest model to your previously unseen test set and make predictions.  Presumably some of these are correct and some incorrect: that test indicates the quality of your predictive model on unseen data

Comment: Thanks, Henry. You saved my life. Basically, I made my final aggregated random forest model from the training set and get the training metric (i.e. training RMSE). I take the same final aggregated random forest that I built to my test data and get the test metric, you mean?

Comment: Yes - the sole purpose of the test data is to see how your model built from the training data would perform with previously unseen cases

Comment: Thanks, Henry for your answer! You are really helpful! I'm an actuary learning ML. It's somewhat hard for me :( I have a question about n-fold CV. Basically, you don't just want to depend on one version of training and testing set because you want to generalise in an unseen data. So, the result from 5-fold CV (i.e. average of 5 test RMSE and average of 5 train RMSE from CV) is going to be more reliable, not likely to overfit. Also, you want to do CV to tune a hyperparameter. I just want to get verified if those two are why we are using cross validation. Thanks, Henry

Comment: The point about validation is that you are still in the process of selecting your model and its hyperparameters, so you run validation many times on the same sets to choose the best; while this is better than just training as it uses non-training data, you still have the risk that this makes you over-optimistic about the model you finally choose since it is in a sense optimised for your particular validation set(s). Cross-validation uses the available data more effectively than simple validation but is otherwise the same issue.